# Using curl to download a private file from S3 bucket using IAM role

Tags: curl, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, chef-infra, amazon-iam

I have a newly created EC2 and it is part of an IAM role, 
Is there a way to use the AWS credential / IAM role to download a file using curl?

I'm trying to solve the catch 22 of getting the first script ( located in S3 ) to invoke my chef-scripts on a new and empty EC2

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using chef server, or alternatively the [hosted service](https://manage.opscode.com/signup) offered by chef?

My point is that the knife command is designed to solve your conundrum. You can use knife to securely bootstrap your new EC2 node:

- https://docs.getchef.com/essentials_nodes_bootstrap.html
- https://docs.getchef.com/install_bootstrap.html
- https://docs.getchef.com/knife_bootstrap.html

I encourage everyone to learn about chef server.